# Error while Connecting PySpark to AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, connection, amazon-redshift

Have been trying to connect Spark 2.2.1 on my EMR 5.11.0 cluster to our Redshift store.

The approaches I followed was -

1. Use the inbuilt Redshift JDBC

   ```
   pyspark --jars /usr/share/aws/redshift/jdbc/RedshiftJDBC41.jar

   from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
   sc
   sql_context = SQLContext(sc)

   redshift_url = "jdbc:redshift://HOST:PORT/DATABASE?user=USER&password=PASSWORD"

   redshift_query  = "select * from table;"

   redshift_query_tempdir_storage = "s3://personal_warehouse/wip_dumps/"        

   # Read data from a query
   df_users = sql_context.read \
       .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
       .option("url", redshift_url) \
       .option("query", redshift_query) \
       .option("tempdir", redshift_query_tempdir_storage) \
       .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true") \
       .load()
   ```

   This gives me the following error -

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 7, in
>      File "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py",
>   line 165, in load
>       return self._df(self._jreader.load())   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call**   File
>   "/usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
>       return f(*a, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line
>   319, in get_return_value ***py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o63.load. : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.redshift. Please find
>   packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html     at***
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:546)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:87)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.databricks.spark.redshift.DefaultSource   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$22$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(DataSource.scala:530)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$22$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(DataSource.scala:530)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$22.apply(DataSource.scala:530)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$22.apply(DataSource.scala:530)
>     at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:530)
>     ... 16 more

Can someone please help tell where I've missed out on something / made a stupid mistake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had to include 4 jar files in the EMR spark-submit options to get this working.

List of jar files:

1.[RedshiftJDBC41-1.2.12.1017.jar](https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/1.2.12.1017/RedshiftJDBC41-1.2.12.1017.jar)

2.[spark-redshift_2.10-2.0.0.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/databricks/spark-redshift_2.10/2.0.0/spark-redshift_2.10-2.0.0.jar)

3.[minimal-json-0.9.4.jar](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json/releases/download/0.9.4/minimal-json-0.9.4.jar)

4.[spark-avro_2.11-3.0.0.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/databricks/spark-avro_2.11/3.0.0/spark-avro_2.11-3.0.0.jar)

You can download the jar files and store them on a S3 bucket and point to it in the spark-submit options like :

```
--jars s3://<pathToJarFile>/RedshiftJDBC41-1.2.10.1009.jar,s3://<pathToJarFile>/minimal-json-0.9.4.jar,s3://<pathToJarFile>/spark-avro_2.11-3.0.0.jar,s3://<pathToJarFile>/spark-redshift_2.10-2.0.0.jar
```

And then finally query your redshift like in this example : [spark-redshift-example](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift#usage) in your spark code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the Spark Redshift datasource to your `pyspark` command:

```
pyspark --jars /usr/share/aws/redshift/jdbc/RedshiftJDBC41.jar \
        --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that spark is not finding the necessary packages in the moment to execute it. To do this at the time of executing the script .sh that launches the execution of the python file you have to add not only the driver but also the necessary package.

## script test.sh

```
sudo pip install boto3

spark-submit --jars RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.15.1025.jar --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.11:2.0.1 test.py
```

## script test.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)

redshift_url = "jdbc:redshift://HOST:PORT/DATABASE?user=USER&password=PASSWORD"

redshift_query  = "select * from table;"

redshift_query_tempdir_storage = "s3://personal_warehouse/wip_dumps/" 



 # Read data from a query



df_users = sql_context.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
    .option("url", redshift_url) \
    .option("query", redshift_query) \
    .option("tempdir", redshift_query_tempdir_storage) \
    .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", "true") \
    .load()
```

## Run the script test.sh

> sudo sh test.sh

The problem must be solved now.