# Transforming a redshift table using Pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I was trying to create a redshift table on top of a current redshift table,
I had a script that does the following steps:

1. load the redshift table into pandas dataframe by chunk to avoid memory error
2. In each chuck, I wrangle the data and output the CSV files into S3
3. Run S3 Copy command to move the files into redshift.

This method is very slow because it keeps querying from Redshift when loading the data into pandas dataframe.

To make the process faster I thought might need to

1. decrease the times I query the original table
2. Use Pyspark instead of Pandas.

I found there is a package call spark-redshift by Databrick but I found it's not maintained for quite a while and seems not working anymore.
I tried to unload the data from to s3 but I don't have the permission to do that due to my role.

So the current method I am trying is to use AWS EMR & Pyspark to do the job, but the hardest part seems to connect the EMR cluster to redshift.
I kept getting  `: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver` error.
I had ssh logged in into master note and download the JDBC jar file, now I really don't know what is missing.

Is there any smart method to replace the slow running job I described above?

Comment: I suppose you can use the PostgreSQL driver for Redshift database, that might be easier for you

Answer (score 1):

Connecting your EMR Spark cluster to Redshift is asked already here: [Error while Connecting PySpark to AWS Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48257351/error-while-connecting-pyspark-to-aws-redshift)

As you can see from the answers, there are number of different ways to get the required dependencies installed into your cluster.

Comment: Thanks so much, regarding my use case, I can also use glue right? I can set up the database connection and crawl the table, let import my table using catalog in a glue job.